# Are there any nice expressions for $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\sqrt{x^2-k^2}\ \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, bessel-functions

In some applied mathematics (ocean modelling) I was doing I came across the integral

$$I(k)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\sqrt{x^2-k^2}\ \mathrm{d}x,$$

where $k\geq 0$ is a constant that depends on the parameters (e.g. flow speed) I wish to use. I was wondering whether anyone knows of a neat expression for this integral, even in terms of Bessel functions? I'm particularly interested in the real part of this integral, that is

$$\Re(I(k))=\int_k^\infty e^{-x^2}\sqrt{x^2-k^2}\ \mathrm{d}x.$$

I was hoping for a solution similar [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614665/integral-int-03-frace-x2-sqrt1-x2-dx) but have had no luck. An asymptotic expression (for large $k$) for $I(k)$ or $\Re(I(k))$ would also be really useful.

Comment: Asymptotic in which direction? Large or small $k$? It would be helpful, however irrelevant you may think it is now, to include all of the context for your problem. You never know who with what kind of experience will happen upon your thread.

Comment: @NinadMunshi large k. I assume for small k, the integral just approaches 1/2. But yes thanks, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: My third and fourth sentences were intended to be independent of my first two questions. What I meant was including the context of the larger problem you are working on that led to these integrals.

Comment: Ah sorry @NinadMunshi, I see what you mean now. I added some context. However, this is a rather specific problem that takes a while to set up. I'm primarily interested in the problem from a mathematical perspective so could even remove all references to applications if that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Substituting $$x = k \cosh t, \qquad dx = k \sinh t \,dt$$
transforms the integral for $\Re(I(k))$ to
$$k^2 \int_0^\infty \sinh^2 t e^{-k^2 \cosh^2 t} \,dt = \frac{1}{4} k^2 \exp \left(-\frac{k^2}{2}\right) \left[K_1\left(\frac{k^2}{2}\right) - K_0\left(\frac{k^2}{2}\right)\right],$$ where $K_\alpha$ is the [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions) of the second kind. Here the equality follows from hyperbolic trigonometric identities and the integral representation
$$K_\alpha(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-s \cosh t} \cosh \alpha t \,dt .$$
Using known expansions for Bessel functions gives that:

- as $k \to \infty$,
  $$\Re(I(k)) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}} {4} \cdot \frac{1}{k} e^{-k^2} \left(1 - \frac{3}{4 k^2} + R_1(k) \right),$$
  where $R_1(k) \in O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$, and
- as $k \to 0$,
  $$\Re(I(k)) = \frac{1}{2} \left[1 + k^2 \log |k| + \left(-\frac{1}{2} + \log 2 + \frac{1}{2} \gamma\right) k^2 + R_2(k)\right],$$
  where $R_2(k) \in O(k^4 \log |k|)$ and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Similarly, the imaginary part of the integral is $$\Im (I(k)) = \int_0^k e^{-x^2} \sqrt{k^2 - x^2} \,dx = \frac{1}{4} \pi k^2 \exp \left(-\frac{k^2}{2}\right) \left[I_0\left(\frac{k^2}{2}\right) + I_1\left(\frac{k^2}{2}\right)\right] ,$$
where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. (Here we've used the principal branch of the square root function; a different choice of branch may yield the negative of this quantity.) Again using known asymptotics for $I_0$ gives asymptotic expansions for $\Im(I(k))$:

- As $k \to \infty$,
  $$\Im(I(k)) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} k \left(1 - \frac{1}{4 k^2} + R_3(k)\right) ,$$
  where $R_3(k) \in O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$, and
- as $k \to 0$,
  $$\Im(I(k)) = \frac{\pi}{4} k^2 \left(1 - \frac{1}{4} k^2 + R_4(k)\right) ,$$
  where $R_4(k) \in O(k^4)$, and

(The leading term of the small-$k$ expansion for $\Im(I(k))$ needs nothing sophisticated, by the way, just the evenness of the integral in $k$ and the formula for the area of a circle.)

Comment: I still wonder why we differ by a factor $2$ in the expansion for large $k$. Any idea ?

Comment: It looks to me like your formula for $\Re(J(k))$ differs from your formula from what you denoted $I(k)$. But perhaps I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 5):

Consider the limit

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}ke^{k^2}\int_k^\infty dx\:e^{-x^2}\sqrt{x^2-k^2}$$

and use the substitution $t^2 = x^2-k^2$

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^\infty dt\:e^{-t^2}\frac{kt^2}{\sqrt{t^2+k^2}}\longrightarrow \int_0^\infty dt\:t^2e^{-t^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$$

by dominated convergence. Therefore

$$\operatorname{Re}\{I(k)\} \sim e^{-k^2}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4k} + O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\right]$$

Answer (score 3):

Using Meijer G-function
$$I(k)=\int_{\color{red}{\large k}}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\sqrt{x^2-k^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}\,  k\,G_{1,2}^{2,0}\left(k^2|
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Expanding for large values of $k$
$$I(k)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4 k}\, e^{-k^2}\left(1-\frac{3}{4 k^2}+\frac{45}{32 k^4}-\frac{525}{128
   k^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^8}\right) \right)$$ which more than decent for $k>3$.

Using @Travis Willse's result for the missing part
$$\Re\Bigg( \int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\sqrt{x^2-k^2}\,dx\Bigg)=$$ $$\frac{\sqrt \pi}{4k} \,e^{-k^2}\,\left(1-\frac{3}{4 k^2}+\frac{45}{32 k^4}-\frac{525}{128
   k^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^8}\right) \right)$$ which seems to be quite decent even for small values of $k$.

In a logarithmic scale

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 2 & -5.6858400 & -5.6507359 \\
 3 & -10.986833 & -10.985083 \\
 4 & -18.243531 & -18.243333 \\
 5 & -27.451780 & -27.451744 \\
 6 & -38.625724 & -38.625716 \\
 7 & -51.774705 & -51.774702 \\
 8 & -66.904827 & -66.904827 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you want a better approximation, transforming the series expansion into a simple $[2n,2n]$ Padé approximant
$$\frac{\sqrt \pi}{4k} \,e^{-k^2}\,\frac{320 k^4+1608 k^2+779}{320 k^4+1848 k^2+1715}$$